# Increment vs Decrement For loop and result is the same

Tags: java

I'm trying to make a json object with the same order as the `inputNames` list.

I tried this:

```
            JSONObject jsonInputs = new JSONObject();
            String[] params = tf.params.split("\\|");
            //get the input descriptions
            List<TestInput> inputNames = TestInput.getInputs(testCaseName);
            for (int i = (params.length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
                jsonInputs.put(inputNames.get(i).getName(), params[i]);
            }
            jsonTest.put("inputs", jsonInputs);
```

and

```
 JSONObject jsonInputs = new JSONObject();
            String[] params = tf.params.split("\\|");
            //get the input descriptions
            List<TestInput> inputNames = TestInput.getInputs(testCaseName);
            for (int i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
                jsonInputs.put(inputNames.get(i).getName(), params[i]);
            }
            jsonTest.put("inputs", jsonInputs);
```

**And the result of the jsonInputs the same.** It's the reverse order of `inputNames`

How do I make it stay in the order that is created?

Comment: So What can be the solution for my problem? Any help?

Comment: for 1st one, it should be `jsonInputs.put(inputNames.get(i).getName(), params[i- (params.length - 1)]);`